# Действие при прокрутке scrollview

Tags: java, android

Есть действие, которое нужно выполнить при прокрутке scrollview. Как можно считать прокручивание? Не обязательно высоту, можно сам факт прокрутки.

Есть панель, которая должна отображаться при прокрутке и должна быть скрыта в начале. Для этого я использую следующий код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


GridLayout fab_panel;
    ScrollView sview;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (!sview.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
            fab_panel.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
}
if (!sview.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            fab_panel.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
}

}
```

но получается так, что панель только остаётся скрытой и не появляется при достижении низа scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно вот [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview):

```
anyScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    float dsy = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View view, int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
        float ydp = y / dsy;
        Log.d("yo", "offset " + ydp);
    }
});
```

для отлова факта достижения нижней границы экрана можно использовать такую конструкцию внутри listener:

```
if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
// bottom of scroll view
}

if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
// top of scroll view

}
```

вот [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316743/detect-end-of-scrollview) есть

Comment: а можно как-то это реализовать чтоб оно срабатывало больше одного раза?

Comment: что значит больше одного раза? это слушатель прокрутки, пока скроллите до тех пор срабатывает

Comment: мне нужно при прокрутке отображать элемент и скрывать его при достижении верха. Но у меня получилось только его скрыть и он не отображается при достижении верха

Comment: сложно говорить об абстрактном коде который есть только у вас на компьютере :( добавьте в вопрос что есть и тогда разговор будет более предметным

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: фух... где этот код расположен? в слушателе или где?

Comment: в коде активити

Comment: мне это ни о чем не говорит, приведите пожалуйста в вопросе полностью метод в котором находятся эти строки

Comment: весь код с активити добавил

Comment: `можно использовать такую конструкцию внутри listener` -  я вот тут писал такое, у вас получается что активность создалась один раз, метод вызвался и все, слушатель же будет обновляться когда вы скроллите, у вас однократно достиглось условие и все

Comment: разобрался, спасибо